# django foreign key saving with file name not object

Tags: python, django, model, django-queryset

I have a model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    thumbnail = models.ForeignKey(Gallery, blank=True, null=True)
```

and my gallery:

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
    media_file = models.FileField(upload_to='somewhere)

def __str__(self):
    return self.media_file
```

in my view:

```
media = Gallery.objects.create(media_file=form.cleaned_data['thumbnail'])
user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=someuser)
user_profile.thumbnail = media
user_profile.save()
```

When I look into admin and user profile model there I dont see image url in thumbnail. I just see `Media Object`. How can I get image url there ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

That is because `self.media_file` will give you the file object not the url to the saved file. Change your code to return the `url` of the file. The easiest could be -

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.media_file.url
```

Read it about here -

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#filefield
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.url